# Pushing data from one array to another based on a condition in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to push all data that meets a condition from one array to another using TypeScript.

```js
    array: any =
    [
      {
        Hostname: 'CBA',
        Certificate_Expiry_Date: 'Thu Mar 25 16:32:48 GMT 2021',
        '': ''
      },
      {
        Hostname: 'CBCB',
        Certificate_Expiry_Date: 'Wed Apr 07 11:19:01 IST 2021',
        '': ''
      },
      {
        Hostname: 'cbcb',
        Certificate_Expiry_Date: 'Thu Apr 01 12:05:22 IST 2021',
        '': ''
      },
      {
        Hostname: 'cbm',
        Certificate_Expiry_Date: 'Sat Apr 04 10:45:19 IST 2020',

    ];

  
  
  alert() {
    if (this.array.Certificate_Expiry_Date > Date) {
      this.array.forEach(item => {
        this.alertsArray.push(
           item.Hostname,
           item.Certificate_Expiry_Date
        );
      });
    }
    console.log(this.alertsArray);
  }
```

I want the above code to push an object into the alerts array when the Certificate exp date is less than 2 months from expiring, but when I try it this way it doesn't work any help is appreciated

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript so there is no difference in how you perform these kinds of operations.

Comment: You need to move the if statement inside the forEach and check for item.Certificate. The array of course doesn't have that field

Comment: What is `Date`? Is it a variable named `Date` or is it supposed to represent the current date?

Comment: If you'd like targeted answers that address your issue, please consider editing the above code so as to constitute a [mcve] as mentioned in [ask].  Right now you're not checking inside the loop and your check seems to be a string comparison unlikely to behave the way you want.  Especially if `Date` is just the [JS date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are try to access an undefined value on the array using dot notation - which isnt available on arrays

```
  alert() {
    if (this.array.Certificate_Expiry_Date > Date) { <--- dot notation on the array wont work
      this.array.forEach(item => {
        this.alertsArray.push(
           item.Hostname,
           item.Certificate_Expiry_Date
        );
      });
    }
    console.log(this.alertsArray);
  }
```

try looping thru the array - checking if your dates are less than 60 days apart - and if so pushing that item into your alerts array

check your condition by turning the expiration and today to new Date() objects converted to milliseconds, then divided the difference by milliseconds in a day, and see if that is less than 60 days.

you may need to tweak the math here to make it work

```
 alert() {
    const milsInDay = (1000*60*60*24);
    const today = new Date().getTime() / milsInDay;
    this.array.forEach((item) => {
       const exp = new Date(item.Certificate_Expiry_Date).getTime() / milsInDay;
       if(exp - today < 60) {
          this.alertsArray.push(item);
       }
    });
    console.log(this.alertsArray);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am currently getting an empty array, but when I console.log the exp dates 1 shows up and im getting NaN for the other 3

Comment: For the empty array - the conditional is not being passed, my math might be a little off there I only did a quick search.  You are getting NaN because JS date objects dont know what IST is `'Sat Apr 04 10:45:19 IST 2020'` so its returning an invalid date error and cant be converted to milliseconds. You might consider changing what the exp date is stored as in the first place.

Comment: It's okay when I get rid of the time and time zone and it works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Awesome - I updated the math - so it should work now! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` to create new array with only elements that match condition and spread (`...`) push those elements into your target array:

```js
this.alertsArray.push(...this.array.filter(elem => elem.Certificate_Expiry_Date > Date));
```

Comment: This will produce an empty array since the values of ```Certificate_Expiry_Date``` are strings and not actual date objects.

Comment: Don’t need the spread operator / push here if you just want the filtered elements. Simple assignment works. If you want to add the filtered, Concat is the better option to avoid mutation

Comment: Note that the OP is pushing two elements into the `alertsArray` for each element in the `array`, which this answer does not do. It's probably best to ask clarifying questions in the comments before answering rather than guessing...

Comment: My answer precisely answers `to push all data that meets a condition from one array to another`. Data types, reassigning array, converting elements after filtering is out of scope based on the original question. I used original question code only as an example without intention to fix any bugs / errors in it.